# Regex - sentence starting with

Tags: regex

I have some text files with a whole bunch of info in them.  Most of the sentences in them start with a certain info list.  Now some items I can extract with other regex codes's (for date, url, email, etc ...) so I'm using them.  But for the other info I have no idea where to start ... .

For example :

```
ITEM_LIST_1 = xxxx .
ITEM_LIST_2 = xxxx .
ITEM_LIST_3 = xxxx .
....
```

I'm looking to create a regex that will extract the xxxx's (sentence) for the specific items.

Thx all

Comment: what kind of regex, java's regex?

Comment: What about `^[^\s]+ = ([^\s]+)`?

Comment: Use `\S` instead of `[^\s]` ... ?

Comment: `\S` (or `[^\s]`) won't work anyway, given the examples they wrote under my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=ITEM_LIST_\d+ = ).*(?= \.)
```

should match the `xxxx` in your example above. It requires a regex engine that allows for arbitrary-length lookaround, though. Most don't (.NET does).

Another option would be

```
ITEM_LIST_\d+\s*=\s*(.*)\s*\.
```

and use match number 1. This requires no lookaround, but matches more than you need and uses a capturing group to select a substring of the total match.

Both could be fine-tuned to your problem with better performance and less chance of matching something wrong if we know what your `xxxx` were.

**EDIT:** If the items are all in a single line, then above regex would fail (since it's greedy):

```
PS> [regex]::matches('Item_List_01 = Chapter1 overview, Who''s who, Chapter2 How to. Item_List_02 = Continue of Chapter2, Problems.', 'Item_List_\d+\s*=\s*(.*)\.') | select groups

Groups
------
{Item_List_01 = Chapter1 overview, Who's who, Chapter2 How to. Item_List_02 = Continue of Chapter2, Problems., Chapt...
```

You can fix it by making it lazy:

```
Item_List_\d+\s*=\s*(.*?)\.
```

which does work, then:

```
PS> [regex]::matches('Item_List_01 = Chapter1 overview, Who''s who, Chapter2 How to. Item_List_02 = Continue of Chapter2, Problems.', 'Item_List_\d+\s*=\s*(.*?)\.') | select groups

Groups
------
{Item_List_01 = Chapter1 overview, Who's who, Chapter2 How to., Chapter1 overview, Who's who, Chapter2 How to}
{Item_List_02 = Continue of Chapter2, Problems., Continue of Chapter2, Problems}
```

However, it will fail again if items have a full-stop in them:

```
PS> [regex]::matches('Item_List_01 = Foo. Bar. Item_List_02 = Baz, gak.', 'Item_List_\d+\s*=\s*(.*?)\.') | select groups

Groups
------
{Item_List_01 = Foo., Foo}
{Item_List_02 = Baz, gak., Baz, gak}
```

This can be solved by adding a lookahead (again) which makes sure that either an end of line/string or another item follows:

```
Item_List_\d+ = (.*?)\.(?=$| Item_List_\d)
```

(Regarding spaces, `\s*`, etc.: I've been a little sloppy here in changing space handling a few times throughout the solutions. You should know what data you're expecting and adapt the regex accordingly. Also you varied the case of `ITEM_LIST`/`Item_List` in your question and comment. You should make that consistent, too.)

Comment: For example : something like  Item_List_01 = Chapter1 overview, Who's who, Chapter2 How to. Item_List_02 = Continue of Chapter2, Problems. etc ...

Comment: It will always be ITEM_LIST ... typo from my side.  And the regex will be used in a small java program.  Thx for all above.